# Upload a file to shared google drive location using Java with Google Drive API V3?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-android-api

I need to upload files to a shared Google Drive location(which is not owned by me, rather shared with me) using Java. Using the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3)s, We can upload files to a drive location which the user owns, But have not found any solution to allow upload to a shared location. The use case is something like different users of an application need to upload files to a shared Google Drive location. There are few other questions( i.e [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807714/file-upload-to-shared-link-of-the-google-drive-using-java-program)) asked on this topic, but none of them has proper answer. Please help if it is possible or please inform it is not possible to achieve this programmatically.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives) you need to add the query parameter ```supportsAllDrives=true``` to be able to access, upload, list or create into a shared drive from the Drive API. Maybe [this Stack Overflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468780/12835757) clarifies this better. **Let me know if that worked or if you need further information.**

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I ll let u know. Thanks a ton

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, It worked, actually as per this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) , they are going to deprecate this parameter, and may be for this reason, they are supporting it by default in their java apis. So actually, I had to do nothing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of fellow commenter @MateoRandwolf, Hence posting the answer. Hope it helps..

As per this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives), the `supportsAllDrives=true` parameter informs Google Drive that your application is designed to handle files on shared drives. But it is also mentioned that the `supportsAllDrives` parameter will be valid until June 1, 2020. After June 1, 2020, all applications will be assumed to support shared drives. So I tried with the Google Drive V3 Java API, and found that shared drives are currently supported by default in the `execute` method of `Drive.Files.Create` class of V3 APIs. Attaching a sample code snippet for others reference. This method `uploadFile` uploads a file to Google drive folder using direct upload and returns the uploaded fileId.

```
public static String uploadFile(Drive drive, String folderId) throws IOException {

    /*
    * drive: an instance of com.google.api.services.drive.Drive class
    * folderId: The id of the folder where you want to upload the file, It can be
    * located in 'My Drive' section or 'Shared with me' shared drive with proper 
    * permissions.
    * */

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);

    File file = drive.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                                    .setFields("id")
                                    .execute();
    System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
    return file.getId();
}
```